Lower bound on $P \left(X > a\right) $ using Paley–Zygmund inequality
I am reading in wiki that for a non-negative random variable X we get
$$\operatorname P \left(X > a\right) \geq \sup_{t > 0 \text{ and } M(t) \geq e^{ta}} \left( 1 - \frac{e^{ta}}{M(t)} \right)^2 \frac{M(t)^2}{M(2t)}\tag{1}$$ mentioning that (1) is derived by applying Paley–Zygmund inequality
$$\operatorname{P}( X > \theta\operatorname{E}[X] )
\ge (1-\theta)^2 \frac{\operatorname{E}[X]^2}{\operatorname{E}[X^2]}\tag{2}$$ on $e^{tX}$ with $0 \le \theta \le 1$.
Using (2) with $E[X]0$ we have a trivial result. Does this mean that using (1) with $E[X]=0$ we will have a trivial results also? I other words is it meaningful to use (1) when $E[X]=0$ ? Finally, in $\sup$, the constraint $M(t) \geq e^{ta}$ mean that we need a lower bound for $M(t)$  to apply (1) it effectively?

Note that (2) holds for nonnegative random variables, so if $X \ge 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0,$ then $X = 0$ a.s., and $P(X > \theta \cdot 0) = 0.$ The inequality is only meaningful if $\mathbb{E}[X] > 0$.

If $t > 0,$ then $$ P(X > a) = P(e^{tX} > e^{ta}).$$ Of course, $e^{tX}$ is nonnegative. Further, if $M(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] > e^{ta},$ then we can further apply Paley-Zygmund as $$ P(e^{tX} >  M(t) \cdot e^{ta}/M(t)) \ge \left(1 - \frac{e^{ta}}{M(t)} \right)^2 \cdot \frac{M(t)^2}{M(2t)},$$ upon noting that $\mathbb{E}[(e^{tX})^2] =M(2t)$. Since the inequality holds for every such $t$ and $a$, we can conclude (1) from the above by supremising over the same. No assumption per se is required on $X$, since we only use Paley-Zygmund for the nonnegative random variable $e^{tX}$.
